Plugin class has no attribute
I'm working on a QGIS plugin and I named my plugin class "ModelGenerator". I've added a QCheckBox (named checkBox) in Qt Designer and I saved it to the .ui file. When calling this checkBox in my main python file (in the run method) I get the following error :
    AttributeError: 'ModelGenerator' object has no attribute 'checkBox' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/atamort/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\model_generator_opendata\model_generator_opendata.py", line 213, in on_checkBox_stateChanged
    if self.checkBox.isChecked():
AttributeError: 'ModelGenerator' object has no attribute 'checkBox'

I might be wrong but doesn't my main Python file have access to the .ui file where the checkBox is defined? Or do I need to convert my .ui file to Python each time I make a change in the .ui?

Probably should be self.dlg.checkBox.isChecked().

You are right, thanks !!

No problem,  you're welcome.
